# C# сравнить файлы на FTP с локальными и скачать не недостающие

Tags: c#, ftp

Есть FTP сервер с файлами и дубликат этих файлов на локальном сервере. Если на FTP добавится файл, как сравнить локальные и FTP файлы а так же скачать новые?

Comment: скачать и сравнить. Если нет, разве-что дату создания сравнить.

Comment: можно md5 сравнивать. если отличаются, то обновить\скачать

Comment: Здравствуйте, решили проблему? Я подобную пытаюсь решить https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/795261/c-ftp-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8, может вы что то подскажете.